# Can I move applications downloaded from the App Store?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I have way too many applications and sadly sometimes I forget if I have an application for a particular purpose.  So I thought I would like to organize /Applications into folders.  For example "Audio, Video, Development, Design, etc."

What will happen when an application updates from the app store?  Will it update the version that is in the folder or will it be downloaded to its original location in "/Applications"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can move the applications. Providing the destination remains in the Spotlight index, the Mac App Store will continue to update the app.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating subfolders that change the directory structure in Finder, you might consider creating folders of related apps in Launchpad, using it as one does the iOS homescreen.

Comment: I tried to use LaunchPad and then at some point my apps got moved around.  So I have a little trust issue with LaunchPad.